# Nodejs and Mysql for Achievements - Performance and scalability

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

## Introduction

I'm setting up a Nodejs server (with socket.io) which will handle users achievements and store them in my Mysql database.

## The Problem

Socket io generates a new unique "socket id" each time a user reloads the page, this means I either have to store the achievement data on the Node server -or fetch it again for every page reload.

***My question***

1. Should I store the Achievement data on my Server - or should I fetch it every time a user needs it?

## Performance wise - thoughts

- My head tells me to store the achievement data on the Node server - as a simple page reload will cause my server to fetch information again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) This is **far** to broad (and in some cases, opinion-based) for SO's Q&A format.

Comment: this question shouldn't be closed. i have a valid solution that is better than what he proposes

Answer (score -1):

Solution to your problem:

1. generate a uuid client side and store it as a cookie and store it in localStorage as backup.
2. on page load check for the uuid. if it doesn't exist, generate it.
3. send the uuid to socket.io when connecting.
4. serverside, use the uuid for storing and retrieving the achievements. you can choose any way of storing this data you like. flat files, relational db's, whatever you like. you could even store it in memory as an object with `uuid` as key, and periodically serialize and store the object as a json file, that way on crash you can reload the json file as your server's "state".

hopefully there is enough here to give you an idea of a good way to address your problem.